# When linking a shared library on linux, are all modules included?

Tags: linux, linker, aix

I'm porting a system of apps from AIX to linux, and all of those apps include a single shared library.  I've got the shared library building on as a linux .so now - and I see at least one post here that describes how to specify what's exported from a shared library (as AIX does via a .exp file).

Just one silly question, though.  On AIX, if a module in a shared library is not referenced by anything in the app that's linking to it, it is ignored by the linker.  That doesn't seem to be the case on linux - but I want to make sure.

While testing my linux shared library, I left out one module with dependencies I wasn't ready to deal with yet (or more accurately, I provided a substitute module with dummy functions for all the entry points to that module, thinking that would allow it to link).  So far, so good.  But when I attempted to link that shared library into a trivial test app, the linker reported unresolved symbols for stuff referenced by *another* shared library module that is itself only referenced from within the module I replaced with dummies.  I.e., I would have expeceted *that* module to simply be ignored...

In other words, this module is being considered by the linker as part of the final application even though nothing in the app references it.  I tried the same experiment on AIX (replacing the same module with dummies and attempting to link a trivial app there).  No complaints.

So, The AIX linker only attempts to resolve shared library module dependencies if those modules *themselves* are explicitly called in from the application.  But the linux linker attempts to resolve dependencies for *all* shared library modules whether they're called in from the application or not.

Is this true?  And if so, is there any way to override that behavior?   Ultimately, when I port everything, all of the dependencies will resolve.  But for now, it's hard to leave something out - even if it's not referenced...

---

Here's a minimal case:

```
main.c contains function main(), which calls function one().
one.c contains function one(), which does nothing.
two.c contains function two(), which calls function three().

There is no function three(), but libshared.so is built from 
modules one.c and two.c.  Program main is built from main.c and
links in libshared.so. 

The linker needs to resolve function one(), which is in the shared
library.  But that's all main.c requires.  Still, function two() in
the library references function three(), which doesn't exist.
The linker will complain about the undefined symbol 'three', even
though program main doesn't need it.
On AIX the linker will not complain and everything will work.

main.c:

    #include <stdio.h>
    int     one();
    int main()
    {
            one();
    }

one.c:

    #include <stdio.h>
    int one()
    {
            return 1;
    }

two.c:

    #include <stdio.h>
    int three();
    int two()
    {
            return three();
    }

build libshared.so with modules one.c and two.c:

    gcc -fPIC -shared one.c two.c -o libshared.so

Attempt to build main from main.c and libshared.so:

    gcc main.c -o main -L. -lshared
    ./libshared.so: undefined reference to `three'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The linker reports an undefined reference to 'three',
which is referenced from two() - but main() doesn't ever call two().
```

Comment: I couldn't follow you, but these things are actually _shared objects_ rather than _shared libraries._ You cannot link a part of the shared object just the whole thing. This is true for both Linux and AIX.

Comment: Okay.  I guess I get the distinction.  But in that case, what the AIX linker does is not attempt to resolve external references in shared object modules that are not themselves referenced by the app being linked.  So, yeah, when the shared library is loaded into memory, the whole thing's there.  But if the shared library has internal dependencies in modules that aren't used in your app, the linker won't complain (and why should it?).  But the linux linker does complain about that, and won't let your build complete.

Comment: To tell the truth, you posts are way too long for my limited attention span -- could you please create a [mcve] ?

Comment: Okay.  I added a minimal reproduceable sample to my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer: *shared libraries* are in fact *shared objects:* they are treated as a single object, not as a *.a library.

This shows that Linux (meaning: glibc/gcc/gold/ld) and AIX have different concepts regarding shared objects.

In Linux, when you link an executable, ld/gold checks the dependencies of the used shared objects as well -- Aix linker doesn't: it assumes that the shared objects are to be used as they are, their dependencies aren't part of the current linking. (At least this is the default behaviour.)

Here is a summary of my tests:

```
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------+
|                |    AIX             |    linux                      |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------+
| libshared.so   |  only with option  |    yes                        |
| can be created |  -Wl,-berok        |                               |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------+
| main           |    yes             |  only with option             |
| can be created |                    |  -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined  |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Note: My random thoughts regarding AIX and linking: http://lzsiga.users.sourceforge.net/aix-linking.html

Answer (score 0):

By default the [GNU binutils linker, `ld`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/) on
Linux requires a symbol `ref` to be defined by some input file (i.e. object file or
shared library) in the linkage if `ref` is referenced by the definition of any
symbol `def` in any input file that the linkage needs. It doesn't matter whether `def` is referenced in turn.

Your program linkage needs `libshared.so`. `libshared.so` defines `two`, which refers to `three`,
so `three` must be defined.

You can countermand this default behaviour to tolerate undefined references in shared libraries
(but not in object files) as follows:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main -L. -lshared -Wl,--allow-shlib-undefined
```

`--allow-shlib-undefined` is documented in [the `ld` manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options)

The notion of *module* in your language corresponds to *translation unit* at the
compilation level and *object file* at the linkage level. It might be helpful to
appreciate that an object file input to the linkage of a ELF program or shared library
has no distinct existence in the program or shared library. It is cut into
pieces and scattered around. So there is no sense in which it would be possible
for a linkage:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main -L. -lshared ...
```

to ignore the unreferenced module `two.(c|o)` within
`libshared.so`. There is no such thing. If that linkage did not need any
definition provided by `libshared.so` then it would ignore the shared library
altogether<sup>1</sup>. If it needs the shared library, then by default its references
must be resolved.

---

[1] That is, on Debian-clan systems where `gcc` is built to invoke `ld` with the `--as-needed` option
by default. On Redhat-clan systems GCC by default links shared libraries if they are input, needed or not.